# Android Studio App with code that is out of date, just wrong, or both

Tags: android

My code below is giving me an issue that the FirebaseRecycleAdapter() cannot be applied.

This is for an app that i am following a tutorial for (not the best but not the worst) and I have tried finding other stack overflow posts and Reddit post but none help. What is said doesn't make since what for I'm trying to do.

```
 FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter =
                new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, PostsViewHolder>
                        (Post.class,
                        R.layout.all_posts_layout,
                        PostsViewHolder.class,
                        PostsRef)
            {
                @Override
                protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PostsViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull Post model) {

                }

                @NonNull
                @Override
                public PostsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                    return null;
                }
            };
```

This is the error I am getting

```
FirebaseRecycleAdapter() in FirebaseRecycleAdapter cannot be applied to:
Expected: Actual
Parameters: Arguments


options: com...com.example.inventorythis.Post> 
         Post.class(java...com.example.inventorythis.Post>) 
         R.layout.all_posts_layout (int)
         PostViewHolder.class (java...MainActivity.PostsViewHolder>)
         PostsRef (com...firebase.database.DatabaseRefrence)
```